# Can I navigate ParentView to another View by button in ChildView?, swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I'm new to SwiftUI and struggling to move MainView to LoginView by clicking Text() in ChildView.

I tried make NavigationView and NavigationLink like this code but it's not working. It's much more complex in real code but I show only simple structure of my code to explain.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var currViewIdx: Int = 0

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      CurrentView(currViewIdx: $currViewIdx)
    }
  }
}

struct CurrentView: View {
  @Binding var currViewIdx: Int

  var body: some View {
    if self.currViewIdx == 0 {
      HomeView()
        .onTapGesture {
            self.currViewIdx = 0
        }
    } else {
      //SomeView.onTapGesture(self.currViewIdx = 1)
    }
  }
}

struct HomeView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
      Text("Go TestView")
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
  }
}

struct TestView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Here is Test View")
  }
}
```

I think, the top hierarchy view, ContentView, has NavigationView and it should be changed when I click Text("Go TestView") in HomeView because it's in NavagationLink.

But the ContentView is not changed to TestView although I touch Text("Go TestView"). How to solve this problem? I considered way to add one more State value to change top level view, but it seems not good if I'll make lots of more values

Thank you